# Updating react root component when its props change

Tags: reactjs

I have a react/redux app which is being embedded on other webpages as a third-party widget.

The app receives a config object from the window object on the page it is embedded on.
Example config object could be:

```
window.appConfig = {
    color: 'blue'
}
```

I want to be able to update the app, when properties on the config object changes.

I have no control over when/if the parent page changes the config object - and in some cases the updates to the config object happens asynchronously after the page is loaded.

Is there a way for the root component's `componentDidUpdate()` to fire when the props update, or how can you listen for updated props?

The index.js file looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App config={window.appConfig} />
    </Provider>,
    window.document.getElementById("root")
)
```

The app.js file looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    // This is not called when config object change
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(this.props)
    }

  render() {
    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2)}</pre>
  }
}

...

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

(A hacky way to detect changes, is to set an interval and check the config object for changes but I would like to avoid that)

Answer (score 0):

instead place the `config` value on the sore and `connect` the component with `redux`store and `dispatch` the changes from  the store when the config updates and it will work fine

```js
// config.js
import store from '../path/to/store'

const updateConfig = (config)=>{
  store.dispatch({
    type:"APP_CONFIG_UPDATE", // add a reducer to catch this and updates it
    payload:config
  })
}
// use the `updateConfig` when change
```

and on the app just deconstruct the config from the redux state

> Note:
>   you can use functional component instead of class and it will updates on props changes without the class life cycle

or:

```js
const updateConfig = (config)=>{
  store.dispatch({
    type:"APP_CONFIG_UPDATE", // add a reducer to catch this and updates it
    payload:config
  })
}

setInterval(()=>{
   const {getState} = store
   cosnt { config } = getState()
  if(compareObjects(window.appConfig,config))
    updateConfig(window.appConfig)

},1000 * 60 /* each minute */)

// for simple object comparisons 
function compareObjects = (obj1,obj2)=>JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Comment: can you provide a basic example to clarify?

Comment: yes sure, but can you tell me how you update the config? where is the part responsible for that

Comment: the "first-party-site" the app is embedded on controls the config object. for example, a simple way to simulate an update, is to just update the window.config from devtools like: `window.config.color = "red"`

Comment: Oh, you have to create an observable pattern to be able to do such thing (hint: using setters and getters )

Comment: i've updated the question to make the case more clear. i'm stuck with the setInterval hack, so open to all ideas...

Comment: if you intention is to be able to change the state from the dev tools you can on the store file `window.store = store //redux store` and from the console `window.store.dispatch({type:"TYPE",payload:data})`

Comment: The app is being embedded as a third-party widget on other websites - so I have no control over when/if the parent page changes the config object - and in some cases the updates to the config object happens asynchronously after the page is loaded. I just want the app to react to the changes. (the devtools example was a way to simulate a config change)

Comment: you can use setInterval to check regularly for an update,check the answer pls